# How to explain the different forms of the Hamilton-Jacobi equation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, phase-space

In Arnold's *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics,* he derives the Hamilton-Jacobi equation (HJE) using a generating function $S_1(Q, q)$ to get

$$
H\left(\frac{\partial S_1(Q, q)}{\partial q}, q, t \right) ~=~ K(Q, t).
$$

However, this is different from what I've seen in other physics texts. For example, Goldstein uses the generating function $S_2(q, P, t)$ to get the equation

$$
H\left(\frac{\partial S_2(q, P, t)}{\partial q}, q, t\right) ~=~ - \frac{\partial S_2(q, P, t)}{\partial t}.
$$

Why is there this difference? Are the two equations saying the same thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main points are:

1. We are studying a [Canonical Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) (CT)
   $$(q,p) \longrightarrow (Q,P) $$ 
   from old canonical coordinates $(q,p)$ and Hamiltonian $H(q,p,t)$ to new canonical coordinates $(Q,P)$and Kamiltonian $K(Q,P,t)$.
2. $S_1(q,Q,t)$ is a so-called [type 1 generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_1_generating_function) of the CT.
3. $S_2(q,P,t)$ is a so-called [type 2 generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_2_generating_function) of the CT.
4. The two types of generating function are connected via a [Legendre transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) 
   $$S_2(q,P,t)-S_1(q,Q,t)~=~Q^i P_i.  $$
5. For all four types of generating functions hold that 
   $$K-H~=~\frac{\partial S_i}{\partial t},\qquad  i~=~1,2,3,4. $$
6. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics,* uses $S_2(q,P,t)$ in the treatment of Hamilton-Jacobi equation. Goldstein assumes that the Kamiltonian $K=0$ vanishes identically.
7. Arnold, *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics,* uses $S_1(q,Q,t)$ in Section 47 and $S_2(q,P,t)$ in Section 48. Arnold assumes (among other things) that $S_1(q,Q,t)$ does not depend explicitly on $t$.

Comment: For the record: J.V. Jose & E.J. Saletan, _Classical dynamics: a contemporary approach,_ also uses a type 1 generating function.