# Hamilton-Jacobi equation and method of solving it

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, phase-space

So, this equation we get when we find [canonical transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) that makes new hamiltonian=0. There are 4 main transformations: F1(q,Q,t), F2(q,P,t), F3(p,Q,t), F4(p,P,t). On practice and in every book I've seen, we use F2 and F1 to solve Hamilton Jacobi equation, but can we use F3 and F4?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/439890/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43221/2451

Comment: Why can't we use F3 and F4?